# GCM push notification with asp.net server in Android app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have integrated **GCM** push notification in my existing android app. Now after updating the app. Some of the devices are getting notification and some are not. Out of 6 installed devices, only two are getting. Not Receiving in Galaxy Nexus and Samsung S3. What might be the reason?????

```
regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());

 if (regId.equals("")) 

            GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), SENDER_ID);
```

This the code to get the Registration Id. Now I have send this id to the third party server(asp.net server). At the server side we are storing those ids in database. And those ids are send to **GCM** server.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: At which state the others fail?

Comment: My application is already live. Today I have updated my app from play store in 5 devices. Then I have send the push notification from 3rd party server. Immediately I have received in HTC and Micromax. But still now its around 4 hours I haven't received in Galaxy Nexus, Samsung S3 and Samsung Ace plus. Its working properly, Bcoz device ids(regids) are getting stored in database(server side). And also I am receiving response true for each id, in server side.

Comment: This might be related to the active google accounts defined on these devices. I am not sure if this is the case in GCM, but in C2DM this account had to be whitelisted. So in order to check this out, log off from the current account in one of these devices, login with a whitelisted google account and try this again